# With My Navigation Bar Is Messed Up

Tags: javascript

Need help with the text on my navigation bar. The items in it are all messed up, and jumbled I know my code is really sloppy I am new to coding. This is the link with JS bin here http://jsbin.com/cibuvozido/edit?html,output

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in your question, don't rely on an external site to host it (though putting full code on an external site is a good *supplement*). Also, the text may be messed up now, but what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: i cant embed pics yet for some reason it is suppose to go straight across th etop and it does but the margin is messsed up somehow bc there all stacked up on eachother and to far or to close

Comment: there suppose to be evenlly spaced out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see the new code with the navbar corrected already, but I recommend that you use a framework starting can be bootstrap or foundation 6 which is also very good.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Contact Us Legacy's Web-Design</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

 
 <style type="text/css">
 
      .home, .security, .contact, .about, .portfolio {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
 
 
 
 .all {
  margin-top:0px;
  position:absolute;
  margin:none;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#008000;
  border-width:4px;
 }
 
 #aside {
  color:#0ddde7;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
  margin:none;
 }
 
 nav {
  border-bottom:solid;
  border-right:solid;
  border-left:solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:#0ddde7;
  border-width:4px;
  /* padding-top:20px; */  
  font-size:1.5em;
  background-color:#0f171b;
  z-index:0;
  
 }
 
 
 h2 {
  text-align:center;
  color:#0ddde7;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  }
  
 h3 {
  text-align:center;
  color:#0ddde7;
  padding: 0 0 0 330px;
  }
  
 .imgg {
  margin-top:24px;
  margin-left:40px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#0ddde7;
  border-width:2px;
  border-radius:18px 18px 18px 18px;
  
 }
 
 .img {
  padding: 14px 0 0 1220px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position:absolute;
 }
 
 #search {
  padding: 0 0 0 1105px;
  height:0;
 
 }
      .jwery {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: table;
      }
 
 .jwery a   {
  -webkit-transition:width 2s; 
  transition: 2s;
}
 .jwery a:hover {
  font-size: 1.1em;
 }
 
 body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#a4a4a4;

 }
 
 
 a:link {color:#0ddde7; text-decoration: underline; }
 a:active {color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline; }
 a:visited {color: #008000; text-decoration: underline; }
 a:hover {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: none; }
 
 </style>

</head>


 
 
       
        <div id="Header">
            
            <div id="search">
            
            
            <form>
  
  <form id="img" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
  
      
         <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="18" maxlength="120">
       
       <input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: 
none; background: url('searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 13px; height: 15px;">
 
  </form>
  
  
 
</div>

<img class="img" src="images/search.png" height="19.4">
    
      
      <nav>
      
      <div class="jwery">
            
        <a class="home" href="Home.html">Home</a>
        <a class="security" href="Security.html">Security</a>
        <a class="FAQ" href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="about" href="About.html">About Us</a>
        <a class="contact" href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
        
        
    </div>
    
    </nav>
 
 <body>
 
 <img class="imgg" src="images/legacy.png" align=left width=300>
 
 <div id="aside">

 <p>You Can Also Email Me At LegacyWebCreations@gmail.com Or Call/Text 252-207-
6688</p>
 
 <p>Feel Free To Leave Me A Message, Question, Comment, Or Recommendation.</p>

<h2>Follow Me! Please Share My Site! </h2>
  
  <h3>Instagram Account: LegacyWebDesign</h3>
  <h3>Personl Account: Surfskateskim57</h3>
  
  <h3>Facebook Account: Ryan Miller</h3>
  <h3>Group Name: LegacyWebDesign</h3>
  
  <h3>Twitter Account:LegacyWebDesign</h3>
  
  <h3>LinkedIn Account: LegacyWebCreations</h3>



 </div>
 
 <div class="all">
 
<a id="foxyform_embed_link_747752" href="http://www.foxyform.com/">Questions?
 Comments?</a>

</div>

  
<script>

(function(d, t){

   var g = d.createElement(t),
       s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];

   g.src = "http://www.foxyform.com/js.php?id=747752&sec_hash=fd11cc5da35&width=380px";

   s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);

}(document, "script"));

</script>


 


 </body>
 
</html>
```

> tell me if this good and only touch the css that I recommend that you
>   place it in the tab that says css which is best practice that placed
>   it directly in the html **See Ya!! and keep on hacking**

Comment: thank u so much and what did u mean that i should use a framework starting can be bootstrap or foundation 6, what is that?

Comment: look for it on the internet have several framework that can facilitate you life with css menus, components of web design and much more, bootstrap is most used and has a steep learning curve low is the most preferred, but foundation 6 has new functionalities and is gaining ground, (sorry for my English). happy night. (one tip... look in youtube these framework courses).